# shell script read arrays and parse the array value to a function

Tags: arrays, shell

I have 2 arrays as follows:

```
Array1 -  ( val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 )
Array2 -  ( user1 user2 user3 user4 user5 )
```

I have one function for each value in `array1`. ex: `Functionval1`, `Functionval2`, `Functionval3`...

Now I need a shell script which will read `array1` and call respective function as well as pass the respective value of `Array2` to the function.

Ex: Read `val1` from `Array1`, for `val1` call `Functionval1` and pass `user1` to the function.

Could you please help me in building logic.

Regards,
Siva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the array indices and call each function and its arguments respectively.

```
Array1=( val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 )
Array2=( user1 user2 user3 user4 user5 )

for i in ${!Array1[@]}; do
    "Function${Array1[$i]}" "${Array2[$i]}"
done
```

Consider a test script like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
Functionval1 (){
    echo "this is a test $1"
}
Functionval2 (){
    echo "this is another test $1"
}

Array1=( val1 val2 )
Array2=( user1 user2 )
for i in ${!Array1[@]}; do
    "Function${Array1[$i]}" "${Array2[$i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
this is a test user1
this is another test user2
```

You could also rewrite the script to do the same thing, without using `${!...[@]}` syntax.

```
Array1=(val1 val2)
Array2=(user1 user2)
arr_len=${#Array1[@]}
let arr_len--
for i in $(seq 0 $arr_len); do
    "Function${Array1[$i]}" "${Array2[$i]}"
done
```

Note that you'd have to adjust this for shells like `zsh` that initiate their first array element to index `1`.

Comment: Hi John, am using ksh. I tried this logic and it is failing with error "${!Array1[@]}: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: This worked for me using Ksh93 and lksh.  See my update.  It's also good to include in the post exactly what shell you're using.

Comment: Hi John,  Thanks a lot this script worked. Now I am able to parse the array values to the function and call the required function. Going forward I will make sure that I will post the environment am using.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked, and welcome to StackOverflow.  If you think this answer is best, you can click the outlined checkmark ✔ next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# functions defined here, e.g Functionval1 etc.

#....

# Array declarations

declare -a Array1=( val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 )
declare -a Array2=( user1 user2 user3 user4 user5 )

# get length of Array1
array1length=${#Array1[@]}

for (( i=0; i<${#Array1[@]}; i++ ));
do
   function_to_run="Function${Array1[$i]}" # E.g. function_to_run becomes Functionval1
   function_parameter=${Array2[$i]} # E.g. function_parameter becomes user1
   $function_to_run $function_parameter # E.g. Functionval1 user1
done
```

You could do it without declaring `function_to_run` and `function_parameter`, but it is a little easier to understand when using them.

Comment: Why offset the array indexes? `for (( i=0; i<${#Array1[@]}; i++ )); do` is cleaner and index arithmetic goes away. All array indexes can be represented with `[$i]` in this case.

Comment: @David - You are totally correct. I have modified it accordingly.

Comment: Hi Warwick, Thanks for the reply.  Sorry for another question. I am a new to shell script and for got to mention that I need ksh script. Could you please help me. Also in above script we are capturing the length of the array1 to array1length.. but we are not using the var in the script. please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: See my alternative answer for using with `ksh`. We only capture the length of the array so that we know how many times to iterate, but the script above will work as expected for `bash`. It will call `Functionval1, Functionval2...`

Answer (score 0):

The Korn Shell version:

```
#!/bin/ksh

# functions defined here, e.g Functionval1 etc.

set -A Array1 val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
set -A Array2 user1 user2 user3 user4 user5

# get length of Array1
Array1length=${#Array1[@]}

i=0
while (( $i < $Array1length ))
do
   function_to_run="Function${Array1[$i]}"
   function_parameter=${Array2[$i]}
   $function_to_run $function_parameter
   i=$i+1
done
```